# Multiplying cells over time

Tags: matlab, matrix, cells

I have two sets of matrices as cells labelled A and B.

The general problem for reference:

I have 5 cells of matrix A (each of which are composed of a 9x9 matrix) and 20 of B (which are also composed of a 9x9 matrix).

I am still trying to find a way to simply make them into the following pattern:

```
A{1}  B{1}  B{2}  B{3}  B{4}
B{5}  A{2}  B{6}  B{7}  B{8}
B{9}  B{10} A{3}  B{11} B{12}
B{13} B{14} B{15} A{4}  B{16}
B{17} B{18} B{19} B{20} A{5}
```

This larger matrix is repeated over time: let's say 5 iterations. So I'm referencing using A{1}(:,:,1) for the data in cell A{1} at time 1.

****My question is something I encountered:****

While this works in a loop with

```
 for j=1:t
    A{1}(:,:,j+1) = B{1}(:,:,j)*A{1}(:,:,j)
 end
```

Why doesn't the following work?

```
 A{1}(:,:,2:t)=B{1}(:,:,1:t-1)*A{1}(:,:,1:t-1);
```

Cheers for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do element-wise multiplication using `.*` instead of `*`. In your example with the loop, you may not notice that you are actually doing matrix multiplication, since your matrices are square at a particular time and the code does not return any error.

Comment: I'd like to do matrix multiplication between A and B. B is in actual fact a vector in my code of dimensions (9,1) in each cell. as I can't make the 2:t work I'll have to change the rest of my code :( Thanks for taking the time though :)

Comment: Then why not to use `for j=1:t-1` for the loop? It should not create an extra time.

Comment: Ah yes, I have done that since posting this question but I'd like to avoid using a loop.

Comment: Why you are so worry about avoiding loop? I think in this case the loop code will be more clear than attempts to vectorize it. With MATLAB JIT optimization you should not have performance issues.

Comment: I see. I was told to avoid loops where possible. Many thanks for your help!